# How do I import an image from the Windows file system in Mathematica Online?

Tags: import, image, files-and-directories, windows

I have an image file named forest.jpg in the C:\Temp directory. I am running Windows Pro 11

Here's what I tried in a new notebook in Wolfram Mathematica Online

image = Import["C:\Temp\forest.jpg"]

I got the message
Import
:File C:\Temp\forest.jpg not found during Import

Would appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. You can upload your file to an online file sharing service (Google drive etc) and generate a public link to use during `Import`. Whether it is still allowed or not depends on the online service's security/access preferences.

Comment: Note that you can also upload files directly to Wolfram Cloud. If you have a paid plan, this is directly accessible (`Upload File(s)` in the top menu), otherwise you have to sneakily create a new file (for example, a Text file, again in the top menu), then copy&paste the contents of your file, save and rename appropriately. Then you can easily access the file from within Wolfram Mathematica Online by `Import[filename]`.

Comment: I had no difficulty importing a jpg file with `Import` in Version 13.3 on Windows 11.